# Is it possible to rename G-suite add-on once published?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, google-apps-script-addon, gsuite-addons

Given we have a published app is it possible to retrospectively change the name that appears in the G-suite Marketplace? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just change the name in the G Suite Marketplace SDK.

Answer (score 0):

In the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK section, chose the "Store Listing" page from the left menu.  Your app's name (along with the short and detailed descriptions) are localized. The editable fields are hidden, until you need to "open" the section (for each language).

https://developers.google.com/gsuite/marketplace/create-listing#app_details